# How to make this return the value in hours : minute : seconds

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

it return the time like :- `2021-05-12 04:38:03.974000`

how should i make it return only the `hour : minute : second`

```
@client.command()
async def timestamp(ctx, id : int):
    a = discord.utils.snowflake_time(id)
    await ctx.send(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `discord.utils.snowflake_time(id)` returns a Python `datetime.datetime` object, which you can quite easily extract hours/minutes/seconds from:

```python
formatted_a = "{:02d} : {:02d} : {02d}".format(a.hour, a.minute, a.second)
```

This is using `{:02d}` instead of `{:d}` so that times like 08:03:05 won't get formatted as 8:3:5.

Comment: This is better than my answer. Did not know this. upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `time.strptime` and `time.strftime` for this:

```
import time
a = '2021-05-12 04:38:03.974000'
formatted_a = time.strftime('%H : %M : %S', time.strptime(a,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
print(formatted_a)
```

output:

```
04 : 38 : 03
```